# getting response code 400 while sending xml as post to web service

Tags: iphone, ios, post, nsurlrequest

I am trying to use a web service built on asp.net wcf from iPhone to POST some data in the form of xml but I am getting the error code 400. I have checked its description and it looks from it that I am not able to create a proper request. can someone please help me in correcting my code which is following:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://172.xxx.xxx.xxx:1230/Service.svc/updateTimesheet"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<TimesheetHour><ContractNote>111</ContractNote><TimesheetHourId>222</TimesheetHourId><TimesheetId>333</TimesheetId><WorkedOn>444</WorkedOn><PlacementOvertimeId>555</PlacementOvertimeId><HoursWorked>666</HoursWorked><PerformancevalueId>777</PerformancevalueId></TimesheetHour>"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:postBody];

NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;  
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];  
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];  
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Response Code: %d", [urlResponse statusCode]);
if ([urlResponse statusCode] >= 200 && [urlResponse statusCode] < 300) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", result);
    //here you get the response 
}
```

**EDIT1:**
server has a method updateTimesheet which expects a class as parameter. The request is defined as XM and response is defined as JSON

**EDIT2:**
below is my code for wcf service:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "updateTimesheet", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
string UpdateTimesheetHours(string ts);
```

[DataContract]
public class TimesheetHour
{
    private int _TimesheetHourId;
    private int _TimesheetId;
    private DateTime _WorkedOn;
    private int _PlacementOvertimeId;
    private decimal _HoursWorked;
    private string _contractorNote = string.Empty;
    private int _performancevalueId = 0;

```
[DataMember]
public string ContractorNote
{
    get { return _contractorNote; }
    set { _contractorNote = value; }
}
[DataMember]
public int TimesheetHourId
{
    get { return _TimesheetHourId; }
    set { _TimesheetHourId = value; }
}
[DataMember]
public int TimesheetId
{
    get { return _TimesheetId; }
    set { _TimesheetId = value; }
}
[DataMember]
public DateTime WorkedOn
{
    get { return _WorkedOn; }
    set { _WorkedOn = value; }
}
[DataMember]
public int PlacementOvertimeId
{
    get { return _PlacementOvertimeId; }
    set { _PlacementOvertimeId = value; }
}
[DataMember]
public decimal HoursWorked
{
    get { return _HoursWorked; }
    set { _HoursWorked = value; }
}
[DataMember]
public int PerformancevalueId
{
    get { return _performancevalueId; }
    set { _performancevalueId = value; }
}
```

}
public string UpdateTimesheetHours(TimesheetHour string)
    {
        return "success";
    }

**EDIT3**
My XML

```
<TimesheetHour>
<ContractNote>111</ContractNote>
<TimesheetHourId>222</TimesheetHourId>
<TimesheetId>333</TimesheetId>
<WorkedOn>444</WorkedOn>
<PlacementOvertimeId>555</PlacementOvertimeId>
<HoursWorked>666</HoursWorked>
<PerformancevalueId>777</PerformancevalueId>
```

i am calling a function on server which expects a string as paremeter and its request type is defined as XML
Thanks

Comment: Could you include the actual post sent to the server?  e.g. the string the above code produces when run in your app.

Comment: A 400 error indicates that you have something wrong with the format of your request. Without knowing the details of what the request should look like (ie what the server is expecting) then it is difficult to know what you are doing wrong.

Comment: NSLog the thing you are passing to server and add that in ur Question. May be then we can help you out.

Comment: Hi all, please check I have added complete code of my service also. sorry for the formatting. did not know how to correct it

Comment: @pankaj You're still not telling us what the server is expecting. All people can do is guess at what is wrong. Add the contract details from the server (ie what is the server expecting?)

Comment: @NickBull Please check my edit 3, i have posted my xml there and also explained about my method on server. I am sorry for not being able to give you guys right information earlier.

Comment: @pankaj But what is your SERVER EXPECTING? All you are giving us is what you are sending to your server. You must have some information regarding what the server is expecting in the XML (do you have  schema, a DTD, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and inspect your request and the server response in more detail. WireShark is free and X11 and Charles has a 30 trial and is native.

Personally I use Charles, down load, launch and it is catching your network traffic, it's that easy.

Comment: I downloaded shark and it helped me a lot in correcting my request. I was getting this error because I had incorrect url in web.config file. I have corrected it and it now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is the wrong format
Try editing these lines :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<TimesheetHour>
 <ContractNote>aaa</ContractNote>
 <TimesheetHourId>bbbb</TimesheetHourId>
 <TimesheetId>cccc</TimesheetId>
 <WorkedOn>dd</WorkedOn>
 <PlacementOvertimeId>eee<PlacementOvertimeId>
 <HoursWorked>ffff</HoursWorked>
 <PerformancevalueId>ggg</PerformancevalueId>
</TimesheetHour>
```

**Also make sure you are not passing string to params that require integer value**. 
This is all I can help you without going in depth.

Seeing your edits what you do is Ids are int defined in your webservices. instead of passing numbers or well if you pass like @"%i , iValue" Something you create like this. Atleast try passing numbers.

Comment: i have tried it by changing the strings to integers but I am still getting the same 400 bad request error

Comment: [request setValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
Try replacing these lines.. I am just pointing you some directions where u can make some changes and have ur code working